# Consecutive days in a data.table resetting by subject

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get the Consecutive_days column to reset by new subject. I am sure it is something simple. I am new to data.table.
Is this possible in data.table or do I need to convert back to a data.frame?

Old data table:

```
DT = data.table(
  Subject = rep(c("A", "B"), 4:3),
  Date = as.Date(
    sprintf("10-%02d-%02d", c(22:25, 25:27), rep(1:2, 4:3)),
    '%m-%d-%y'
  )
)
DT[]
#    Subject       Date
# 1:       A 2001-10-22
# 2:       A 2001-10-23
# 3:       A 2001-10-24
# 4:       A 2001-10-25
# 5:       B 2002-10-25
# 6:       B 2002-10-26
# 7:       B 2002-10-27
```

What I tried:

```
DT[, Consecutive_days := c(0,diff(Date)), by =.(Subject)]
```

What happened:

```
#    Subject       Date Consecutive_days
# 1:       A 2001-10-22                0
# 2:       A 2001-10-23                1
# 3:       A 2001-10-24                1
# 4:       A 2001-10-25                1
# 5:       B 2002-10-25                0
# 6:       B 2002-10-26                1
# 7:       B 2002-10-27                1
```

I am trying to get it do; reset every time the `Subject` changes

```
#    Subject       Date Consecutive_days
# 1:       A 2001-10-22                0
# 2:       A 2001-10-23                1
# 3:       A 2001-10-24                2
# 4:       A 2001-10-25                3
# 5:       B 2002-10-25                0
# 6:       B 2002-10-26                1
# 7:       B 2002-10-27                2
```

Comment: Something has clearly gone funky here. With `by=.(Subject)` you should definitely get a reset. Also, your code as shown should only ever give `1` day difference, as that is always the case in the data as shown. Maybe try with a fresh R session.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out I made the adjustments, it was my mistake.

Comment: @PanDora, what if there are two non-consecutive dates within a same group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not simply adding a grouping statement `by = Subject` to calculate it group_wise and just `cumsum` the difference field you've already calculated.

```r
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(
  Subject = rep(c("A", "B"), 4:3),
  Date = as.Date(
    sprintf("10-%02d-%02d", c(22:25, 25:27), rep(1:2, 4:3)),
    '%m-%d-%y'
  )
)

DT[, cons_days := cumsum(c(0, diff(Date))), by = Subject]
DT
#>    Subject       Date cons_days
#> 1:       A 2001-10-22         0
#> 2:       A 2001-10-23         1
#> 3:       A 2001-10-24         2
#> 4:       A 2001-10-25         3
#> 5:       B 2002-10-25         0
#> 6:       B 2002-10-26         1
#> 7:       B 2002-10-27         2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
DT[, group := cumsum(c(2, diff(Date)) != 1), by = Subject]
DT[, Consecutive_days := seq_len(.N) - 1, by = .(Subject, group)]
DT[, group := NULL]

   Subject       Date Consecutive_days
1:       A 2001-10-22                0
2:       A 2001-10-23                1
3:       A 2001-10-24                2
4:       A 2001-10-25                3
5:       B 2002-10-25                0
6:       B 2002-10-26                1
7:       B 2002-10-27                2
```

if you want to have same dates in same group then change into `cumsum(c(2, diff(Date)) > 1)`

Comment: This is a good answer but it could go for some more explanation of what you've done/why it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution despite the fact you were looking for a `data.table` one in case you were also interested:

```
library(dplyr)

DT %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  mutate(Consecutive_days = cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(Date, lag(Date, default = first(Date)), units = "days"))))


# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Subject [2]
  Subject Date       Consecutive_days
  <chr>   <date>                <dbl>
1 A       2001-10-22                0
2 A       2001-10-23                1
3 A       2001-10-24                2
4 A       2001-10-25                3
5 B       2002-10-25                0
6 B       2002-10-26                1
7 B       2002-10-27                2
```